# Error defining function in Polymer 2.0

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

I want to toggle the `paper-drawer` by clicking the menu button in the upper left of the toolbar. The problem is I get the following error in the console:

> "ReferenceError: _toggle is not defined
>       at HTMLElement.onclick (http://null.jsbin.com/runner:1:1805)"

[Here is the JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/degifisici/1/edit?html,console,output).

http://jsbin.com/degifisici/1/edit?html,console,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>

  <base href="http://polygit.org/polymer+:master/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer-element.html">
  <link rel="import" href="app-layout/app-layout.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-icon/iron-icon.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-item/paper-icon-item.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">

</head>
<body>
  <dom-module id="my-el">
    <template>
      <app-header reveals>
        <app-toolbar>
          <paper-icon-button icon="menu" onclick="_toggle"></paper-icon-button>
          <div main-title>My app</div>
          <paper-icon-button icon="delete"></paper-icon-button>
          <paper-icon-button icon="search"></paper-icon-button>
          <paper-icon-button icon="close"></paper-icon-button>
          <paper-progress value="10" indeterminate bottom-item></paper-progress>
        </app-toolbar>
      </app-header>
      <app-drawer id="drawer" swipe-open></app-drawer>
    </template>
    <script>
      class MyEl extends Polymer.Element {
        static get is() { return 'my-el' }

        constructor() {
          super();
        }

        ready() {
          super.ready();
        }

        _toggle() {
          var drawer = this.$.drawer;
          drawer.toggle();
        }

      }
      customElements.define(MyEl.is, MyEl);
    </script>
  </dom-module>

  <my-el></my-el>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `onclick` to `on-click` and probably you'll need to import `gestures-event-listener` also.

```
<link rel="import" href="polymer/lib/mixins/gesture-event-listeners.html">
```

Comment: I believe you don't need "gesture..." import with on-click. However it's better to use on-tap instead of on-click, because on-tap works also with touch devices (mouse clicks are supported too). On-tap requires "gesture..." import.